# Javascript Shortcode Parse

Tags: javascript, regex

I need to parse following shortcode, for example my shortcode is :

```
[shortcode one=this two=is three=myshortcode]
```

I want to get **this**, **is** and **myshortcode** and add to array so it will :

```
['this', 'is', 'myshortcode']
```

NOTE : I know generally shortcode parameter marked with " and " ( ie [shortcode one="this" two="is" three="myshortcode"] ), but I need to parse shortcode above without ""

Any help really appreciated

Comment: Do you actually have a question?

Comment: Writing a regular expression starts with formalising the requirements. Try to write down a "rule" that would help a person not familiarised with programming to take the `[shortcode one=this two=is three=myshortcode]` string on paper and extract the required data, manually. Once that is done - it's your 70% of success.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here you go I have built a perfectly scalable solution for you. The solution works for any number of parameters.

```js
function myFunction() {
    var str = "[shortcode one=this two=is three=myshortcode hello=sdfksj]";
var output = new Array();
    var res = str.split("=");
for (i = 1; i < res.length; i++) { 
var temp = res[i].split(" ");
if(i == res.length-1){
temp[0] = temp[0].substring(0,temp[0].length-1);
}
output.push(temp[0]);
}
    document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = output;
}
```

```html
<button onclick="myFunction()">Try it</button>

<p id="demo"></p>
```

Answer (score 2):

I'm assuming you want to parse the first string with Regex and output the three elements  in order to add them to an array later. That seems rather simple, or am I misunderstanding what you need? I'm assuming the word `shortcode`is as it will be in your string. You'd probably need two regex operations if you haven't located and isolated the shortcode string yet that you posted above:

```
/\[shortcode((?: \S+=\S+)+)\]/
```

Replacement: `"$1"`

If you already have the code exactly as you posted it, then you can skip the regex above. At any rate, you'll have end with the following regex:

```
  / \S+=(\S+)(?:$| )/g
```

You can then add all the matches to your array.

If this is is not what you're looking for, then perhaps a more real example of your code would help.

Comment: thanks, but the attribute is conditional, sometimes users can generate with [shortcode one=this two=is three=myshortcode another=blah etc=blahblah], so the attribute not only one, two and three

Comment: Okay, so the parameter is always constructed in this way: [shortcode  word=word  word=word word=word word=word...]? And the word "shortcode" is always literally "shortcode"?

Comment: Can you please give me example usage?

Answer (score 0):

```
var str="[shortcode one=this two=is three=myshortcode]";
eval('var obj=' + str.replace(/shortcode /,"").replace(/=/g,"':'").replace(/\[/g,"{'").replace(/\]/g,"'}").replace(/ /g,"','"));
var a=[];
for(x in obj) a.push(obj[x]);
console.log(a);
```

You can try the above code.

Comment: Wouldn't `str.replace(/shortcode /,"")` replace `three=myshortcode`? Thus, affecting the final result?

Answer (score 0):

Here's my solution: https://jsfiddle.net/t6rLv74u/

Firstly, remove the `[shortcode` and trailing `]`

Next, split the result by space `" "`

After that, run through the array and remove anything that's on and before =, `.*?=`.

And now you have your result.